How can I set my solver in Excel to find the closest result to a certain value?
    `Sub Leagues_Solver()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 30

' Leagues_Solver Macro
'Reset Solver
SolverReset

mytarget = Range("$A$1").Offset(i, 0)

'
    SolverOk SetCell:=Sheets("Footballprediction.ai Stats LG").Range("$C$1").Offset(i, 0).Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=mytarget, ByChange:=Sheets("Footballprediction.ai Stats LG").Range("$K$2").Offset(i, 0).Address, Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheets("Footballprediction.ai Stats LG").Range("$K$2").Offset(i, 0).Address, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheets("Footballprediction.ai Stats LG").Range("$K$2").Offset(i, 0).Address, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverSolve (True)
    
    'Approve the solution and avoid the popups
    
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    
    Next i
       
End Sub




(A)Value to Reach
(C)Average-Conf.int
(K)Alpha
(L)Stand.Dev.
(M)Sample
(N)Conf.Int.
(O)Average




2,000
#NUM!
0,000
1,826
4
#NUM!
4,000



This above is my code and the first row of my table. My main goal is to set Column C to the Value of Column A which is in this case 2, but the problem is that by changing alpha there isn't a possibility where Column C could be equal exactly 2, but it would be perfectly good for me if it could be approximately 2, For example.: correct for 2 or 3 decimals. I don't know if this is understandable, but thank you for the help!

In my code Columns A and C starts in the second row too, I just haven't added headers up until now.

SolverOk SetCell:="$B$2", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$K$2", Engine:=1 _
    , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

Set the target value as
=abs(a2-c2)


Then include 1st line above within your solver loop (VB) so as to change cell K2.offset to minimize the B2.offset.
This will get you as close as you can get - which should avoid issues RE: 'solver failed to converge' in the case of 'exact match' which is what you were attempting.
Modify as required to allow for the desired restrictions (e.g. 0-1).
FYI - if you aim to get confidence interval = 0, rather minimize its absolute value (if it can even go negative to begin with).
Also - the initial estimate is usually quite important for ultimately converging. You might want to obtain a better intial guess to begin with (with goal seek for instance - which you can record a macro / tailor as req.) to automate.
PPS - the code you provided doesn't seem to align with sample table - given your target appears to reference the header in the table (while other cells start in row 2 as opposed to row 1) - maybe that's all you need to do different.
Go luck with that..
